# How do you find the coefficients of a Polynomail SVM in scikit-learn and what is the gamma?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, polynomials, coefficients, gamma-distribution

> coef_ : array, shape = [n_class * (n_class-1) / 2, n_features]
>   Weights assigned to the features (coefficients in the primal problem). This is **only available** in the case of a **linear kernel**.
>
> coef_ is a readonly property derived from dual_coef_ and support_vectors_.

I don't understand this. If I use PolynomialFeatures on X, I can use a linear kernel and read the resulting coefficients/weights. Is the polynomial kernel the same thing as using PolynomialFeatures?
How do you read the coef_ values for the fit() on the training data?

How is gamma related to this? Isn't gamma:

```
Gamma = 1/2*sigma^2
```

How is that related to a polynomial? I'ts not only an rbf thing?